# Good library for pairing based cryptography in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am looking for a good library that can perform [pairing based cryptography (PBC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing-based_cryptography).
One I could find is [jPBC](http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/)

What have others used? and their experiences?

The idea is to test the performance of algorithms using standard pairings ([Weil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_pairing), [Tate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate_pairing)) as well as some of the newer proposals without getting my hands too much dirty in the math.

Comment: There are many pairing-based crypto libraries and a good chunk is for Java. [Here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/f2d720010506569d3a39) is a small list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do work in this space as well. The best thing we could find in java was jPBC. Its not very good.

**Non java alternatives:**

- [MIRACL](https://github.com/miracl/MIRACL): I believe this is the  current
  fastest c implementation.
- [charm crypto](http://charm-crypto.com/Main.html):  a python framework for
  rapidly prototyping crypto systems. Full disclosure, I am a dev on
  it. It has bindings to some subset of  MIRACL and Lynn's  PBC lib.
  These are more than enough to impliment most schemes.These subsets
  are expanding and probably can be readily expanded without getting
  into the math involved. Given specific requests, we might even be willing to do those
  extensions

  Furthermore, it already has support for benchmarking that can
  give specific time spent in cryptographic operations, the number of operations (e.g.
  pairings and exponentiations), and other stats.

Comment: Thanks. Is the MIRACL support better than what is in jPBC. It might be worthwhile to write a better Java library. Could you please write a bit on why you feel jPBC is not very good? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MIRACL is the gold standard for Elliptic Curve Cryptography over GF(p) and GF(2m) and additionally supports even more esoteric Elliptic Curves and Lucas function-based schemes. It also includes over twenty protocols based on the new paradigm of Pairing-Based Cryptography.   Using MIRACL means that AES encryption, RSA public key cryptography, Diffie-Hellman Key exchange and DSA digital signature are all just a few procedure calls away.

You can read more about MIRACL here and download the SDK: https://github.com/miracl/MIRACL

Comment: Is this library updating in the future?

Answer (score 2):

An open-source java implementation of Miracl is at
 https://dsl-external.bbn.com/tracsvr/openP3S/wiki/jmiracl
Includes benchmarks

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Comment: This looks promising. Has anyone used it? Feedback would be appreciated.