# Request for Attribute based Encryption pseudocode or java code (Jpbc library)

Tags: jpbc

I want to implement the bilinear pairing Attribute based Encryption using Jpbc library. However, I could not find any pseudocode or code. Could you help me to find the pseudocode or code of ABE. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure about what you exactly want. JPBC is a pairing library for Java. ABE is an encryption cipher. One is a mathematical tool to build an encryption cipher; the other is a cipher found in already-built libraries. So I will try to address everything you say in your question:

> I want to implement the bilinear pairing Attribute based Encryption using Jpbc library

If you need a pairing library in Java, jPBC is your best option [although it is not very good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812829/16289263). As the authors mention, MIRACL is a good non-java alternative. [Charm](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm) can also be a good option, either to build your own ABE implementation (something I do not recommend unless you are a cryptographer with implementation experience) or use some of theirs.

> Could you help me to find the pseudocode or code of ABE

If what you want is a Java Implementation of ABE schemes, there are the following libraries available on GitHub:

- [CP-ABE](https://github.com/junwei-wang/cpabe/)
- [DET-ABE](https://github.com/mmoraless/DET-ABE)
- [JCPABE](https://github.com/TU-Berlin-SNET/JCPABE)

You should consider that these libraries have no maintenance or an active community.

---

Finally, in case you find it useful, and if you are willing to use other languages, some other ABE implementations are:

- [Charm (Python)](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm)
- [Rabe (Rust)](https://github.com/Fraunhofer-AISEC/rabe)
- [OpenABE (C++)](https://github.com/zeutro/openabe)