# implementing CP-ABE in a Node.js and blockchain project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am unable to find a JavaScript library that allows me to implement a CP-ABE (Attribute-Based Encryption) policy in my project. Is there anyone who can assist me in finding a suitable solution?

im expecting to find a library

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this post is old, but in case someone finds this info useful, a similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74090578/16289263), and the answers mentioned that the top maintained libraries for CP-ABE are written in Python, C++ or Python.

A project provides [Node.js bindings](https://github.com/lilezek/node-cp-abe) to CP-ABE but seems no longer maintained. Instead, since you are working with Blockchain maybe this [Go library called GoFE](https://github.com/fentec-project/gofe) may be a good choice too.

---

***Edit [11/03/2024]***

It should be noted out that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74090578/16289263) referred to a library for Java, not JavaScript. However, the answers provided a brief ABE library review and noted how the maintained libraries seemed to be written in Python ([Charm](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm)), Rust ([Rabe](https://github.com/Fraunhofer-AISEC/rabe)) or C++ ([OpenABE](https://github.com/zeutro/openabe)).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35734368)